# Python list with dict should have same key

Tags: python

I want my_list should have a dict with same key but with multiple values

```
my_list = []
my_dict = {}
old_list = ['1','2','3','4','5']
for i in old_list:
    my_dict['Cidr'] = i
    my_list.append(my_dict)
print(my_list)
```

OutPut:

```
[{'Cidr': '5'}, {'Cidr': '5'}, {'Cidr': '5'}, {'Cidr': '5'}, {'Cidr': '5'}]
```

Expected output should be:

```
[{'Cidr': '1'}, {'Cidr': '2'}, {'Cidr': '3'}, {'Cidr': '4'}, {'Cidr': '5'}]
```

Comment: You should create a new dict at each iteration rather than inserting the same dict 5 times. Your dict simply stores the value from the last update.

Answer (score 5):

Your dict is getting mutated - you only have one dict and every loop you just change the value at key 'Cidr'. The array contains 5 references to the same dict.

What you need to do is create a new dict each time you do the loop:

```
my_list = []
old_list = ['1','2','3','4','5']
for i in old_list:
    my_dict = {}
    my_dict['Cidr'] = i
    my_list.append(my_dict)
print(my_list)
```

That way each element in the array will have it's own dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
my_list = []
old_list = ['1','2','3','4','5']
for i in old_list:
    my_dict = {}
    my_dict['Cidr'] = i
    my_list.append(my_dict)
print(my_list)
```

Comment: How to replace [{'Cidr': '1'}, {'Cidr': '2'}, {'Cidr': '3'}, {'Cidr': '4'}, {'Cidr': '5'}] with [{"Cidr": "1"}, {"Cidr": "2"}, {"Cidr": "3"}, {"Cidr": "4"}, {"Cidr": "5"}] i dont see replace method for list

Comment: my_list = str(my_list).replace("'",'"')

Answer (score 2):

Try use a [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

```
import copy
my_list = []
my_dict = {}
old_list = ['1','2','3','4','5']
for i in old_list:
    my_dict['Cidr'] = i
    my_list.append(copy.deepcopy(my_dict))
print my_list
```

Answer (score 2):

```
old_list = ['1','2','3','4','5']
my_list = [{'Cidr': i} for i in old_list]
```

Comment: This is a nice way of doing it, but it doesn't explain the problem or help OP learn.