# Need help to understand python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

Could someone explain me why the output of this code is same value using a dictionary? I thought if I add a key to the corresponding variable dictionary I can manipulate it's values.

Thanks for the help.

```
>>> sample = {}
>>> listDict1 = {}

>>> listDict1['a'] = 'b'
>>> listDict1['c'] = 'd'

>>> sample["item1"] = listDict1

>>> listDict1['a'] = 'x'
>>> listDict1['c'] = 'y'

>>> sample["item2"] = listDict1

>>> sample
{'item2': {'a': 'x', 'c': 'y'}, 'item1': {'a': 'x', 'c': 'y'}}
```

I expected:

```
{'item2': {'a': 'x', 'c': 'y'}, 'item1': {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}}
```

Comment: you've reused the same reference. Copy the dict instead using `sample["item1"] = dict(listDict1)` for instance.

Comment: check out `id(sample['item1'])` and `id(sample('[item2'])` , they are same , it means they both refers to same references.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected Data Assignment in Python Nested Dictionaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511394/unexpected-data-assignment-in-python-nested-dictionaries)

Comment: @Jean hi sir thanks for the fast response. But why do i need to add dict(listDict1) if the python knows it as a dictionary? just want to understand the python dictionary sir...

Comment: @Arman hi sir i didn't know that, yes you're correct it's same id.

Comment: dict(listDict1) creates a new dictionary instead of using a reference to the old one

Comment: Your code creates two names for one object. If `A` is a dictionary and you run the code `B = A`. Then `A`, `B` are two names for 1 dictionary, not two separate dictionaries.

Comment: hi thanks for all the response i think i'm slowly grasping now the python dictionary..i edit the code and used this.

sample = {}

listDict1 = {}


listDict1['a'] = 'b'
listDict1['c'] = 'd'

sample["item1"] = dict(listDict1)

listDict1['a'] = 'x'
listDict1['c'] = 'y'

sample["item2"] = dict(listDict1)


print id(sample["item1"])
print id(sample["item2"] )
print sample

Comment: @iamcoder: This is not just related to dictionaries - all names in Python are just references to objects. Even if you do `a = 2`, then `a` is just a name that points to the integer object `2`. Read [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by Ned Batchelder.

Comment: @Tim hi sir, thanks for the clarification i will read the link you gave and understand more the python language.

Answer (score 1):

using the above suggestion comments, i edit the code and works perfectly fine.
Thanks.

sample = {}

```
listDict1 = {}


listDict1['a'] = 'b'
listDict1['c'] = 'd'

sample["item1"] = dict(listDict1)

listDict1['a'] = 'x'
listDict1['c'] = 'y'

sample["item2"] = dict(listDict1)


print id(sample["item1"])
print id(sample["item2"] )
print sample

OUTPUT:
40012512
40012656
{'item2': {'a': 'x', 'c': 'y'}, 'item1': {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}}
```